# Seemingly equivalent list initialization results in different behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm solving [this challenge on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array/problem) in Python 3 and came up with the following solution:

```
def dynamicArray(n, queries):
    seqList = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    lastAnswer = 0
    result = []

    for query in queries:
        if query[0] == 1:
            seqList[(query[1] ^ lastAnswer) % n].append(query[2])
        elif query[0] == 2:
            seq = seqList[(query[1] ^ lastAnswer) % n]
            lastAnswer = seq[query[2] % len(seq)]
            result.append(lastAnswer)

    return result
```

This works fine and passes all test cases.

The problem is when i change the initialization of `seqList` from the following:

```
seqList = [[] for _ in range(n)]
```

To this:

```
seqList = [[]] * n
```

Then all test cases fail and i cannot figure out why. There are no other changes in the code.

I've even created the following simple test case just to compare the results of these initialization methods:

```
n = 3

a1 = [[]] * n
a2 = [[] for _ in range(n)]

print(a1)
print(a2)
print(a1 == a2)
```

And the result is as expected:

> [[], [], []]
>
> [[], [], []]
>
> True

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain this behavior to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
seqList = [[]] * n
```

is the same as this:

```
lst = []
seqList = [lst for _ in range(n)]
```

When you use `*` to create lists, Python doesn't do any copying. All sublists reference the same list. So this line:

```
seqList[(query[1] ^ lastAnswer) % n].append(query[2])
```

appends to all the lists.

Answer (score 1):

It might appear the same till here as you show:

```
n = 3

a1 = [[]] * n
a2 = [[] for _ in range(n)]

print(a1)
print(a2)
print(a1 == a2)
```

Output:

```
True
```

But here is where the difference is visible:

```
a1[0].append('_')
a2[0].append('_')
print(a1)
print(a2)
```

Output:

```
[['_'], ['_'], ['_']]
[['_'], [], []]
```

This is because lists are "mutable" data type. The two initialization styles work in different ways: In first one compiler builds it all at once (and hence will be faster) whereas second one builds incrementally. With immutable data-types you wont see anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

```
n = 5
seqList = [[] for _ in range(n)]
seqList
>>[[], [], [], [], []]

seqList[0].append(8)
seqList
>>[[8], [], [], [], []]
```

Method 2:

```
seqList2 = [[]] * n
seqList2
>>[[], [], [], [], []]

seqList2[0].append(8)
seqList2
>>[[8], [8], [8], [8], [8]]
```

Method 2 creates a list of lists and each member list refers to the same list instance.

`[[] for _ in range(n)]` evaluates or creates a `[]` once for each iteration of `n` whereas `[[]] * n` evaluates `[]` only once. Hence only one instance is created